# How to make a set of Enums map to a Postgresql array in Kotlin

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, kotlin, jpa

I want to map a `Set` to a postgresql array type with Hibernate 6 and Kotlin. I've got it working with a `List` type but it seems like there isn't an out of the box type value for sets? Do I have to make that type for myself to get this working like I want?

Working code:

```
@Type(
    value = ListArrayType::class,
    parameters = [
        Parameter(
            name = ListArrayType.SQL_ARRAY_TYPE,
            value = "house"
        )
    ]
)
@Column(
    name = "houses",
    columnDefinition = "house[]"
)
val houses: List<House>,
```

This is with hypersistence-utils version: `io.hypersistence:hypersistence-utils-hibernate-62:3.6.0`. When I update to `io.hypersistence:hypersistence-utils-hibernate-63:3.7.1` even this stops working with the error:

```
Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column [houses] in table [dok_card]; found [_house (Types#ARRAY)], but expecting [house[] (Types#OTHER)]
```